# Add Session Value to HiddenField placed in web control

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="mypostID" runat="server" Value=""/>
```

I wanted to ask if I could do something like:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="mypostID" runat="server" Value="<% Response.Write(Session["ïd"])%>"/>
```

I cannot access the session from the user control code behind but if I put a Respose.Write on the page itself it shows the session value.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about a webcontrol or a usercontrol? Title states webcontrol body states usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTPContext.CurrentContext.Current.HTTPSessionState to access session states from the code behind of the control.

Comment: 'System.Web.HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'CurrentContext'

Comment: Sorry, use System.Web.HttpContext.Current..HTTPSessionState instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the Fully Qualified Namespace for the HTTP Session in this case, because you're in a user control.

When you do `Session["foo"]` in a user control, it will access the `UserControl.Session` property (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.session(VS.71).aspx)), not the `HttpContext.Session`.

So do it like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session("foo")
```

See more details on HttpContext.Current.Session [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Is it possible that some other code is causing your error? Just maybe??? It would also help if you gave more details on the error you're getting, rather than just posting an error and expecting us to piece it together. You also know that if you try to access something which isnt there, you will get a NullReferenceException. Is it possible you're not adding the object to the session properly?